# How to order the app engine versions in gcloud based on LAST_DEPLOYED

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I would like to show the latest version generated in app engine, I have this:

```
gcloud app versions list --sort-by=~VERSION
```

when executing the command it shows me:
[image: output]

I would like to sort by string based on the name of the version and that the output is only the latest version.
I pray you can help me.
Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gcloud app versions list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/list) command accepts a `--limit` option which may be handy to obtain what you want:

> `--limit=LIMIT`
>
> Maximum number of resources to list. The default is `unlimited`. This
>   flag interacts with other flags that are applied in this order:
>   `--flatten`, `--sort-by`, `--filter`, `--limit`.

So you could get a single entry using `--limit=1`

To get the latest as opposed to the oldest you *may* need to reverse the sorting order, which is possible using the `~` prefix:

> `--sort-by=[FIELD,…]`
>
> Comma-separated list of resource field key names to sort by. The
>   default order is ascending. Prefix a field with ``~´´ for descending
>   order on that field.

Note that you may need to get rid of (some of) the versions that use different name formats than the default, timestamp-based one (like the `a2` and `v2` ones showing in your current list) for the scheme to work.

Side note: you may want to stop some of those versions - they all appear running now, possibly unnecessarily chewing resources and driving up costs.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the version ID of the last deployment

```
gcloud app versions list --sort-by="~last_deployed_time" --limit=1 --format="value(id)"
```

If you want to sort by version string use this one

```
gcloud app versions list --sort-by="~id" --limit=1 --format="value(id)"
```